# ASP.NET WEB API - Collecting model state errors from all Custom Validation Attributes

Tags: asp.net

I am doing a project in ASP.NET Web API. I have written different custom Validation Attributes. Now the problem is, I am getting model state errors from only one Attribute which runs first. Please help me to combine the model state errors from all validationAttributes.

Ex.  I have some custom validation attributes like following:

```
public class PhoneNumberFormatAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
     .......
     return new ValidationResult("Invalid Phone Number);
     .......
}
```

---

```
public class RangeValueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    .........
    return new ValidationResult("Invalid Range");
    ..........
 }
```

Now I want to collect all validation errors in ModelState. But now I get from only one custom validation attribute which runs first.

Any of your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since the errors are an enumeration you need to use:

```
yield return new ValidationResult("Invalid Phone Number);
```

That allows it to return and then do the next one in the iterator.